# Write regex for path changes in VSCode

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

At work, I often have to change the paths of files. For example, there is:

```
qwerty123/aasdad/index.js 
qwerty321/ewqewe/script.js
```

I need to replace it with

```
js/index.js
```

There are also pictures and css files. They are always in the img and css folders. So I couldn't get it right. My mind was not enough =( Changing paths for this small task takes about 10 minutes, it's a pity to spend them on this.

Tried this:
`src="(.*)" ".*/(.+)\.jpg"`
but it also cuts out the file name, but I need it.

Comment: Separate this into two questions and show example paths of your second question about the images in the other question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find: `[^\s]*\b(\/.*\.js\b)`
Replace: `js$1`

If your paths have spaces in them the find regex won't work as the demo shows!

See [Rege101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/bdMCTB/1)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Its work! i spent 5 hours on this =)